# How can I use Bitbucket Server with Google Container Builder

Tags: bitbucket, google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I understand today we can use Github, Atlassian Bitbucket (Cloud) and Google Code Repository. Is it possible to use BitBucket Server? We do have network connectivity to the BitBucket Server from the GCP Project where we'll be doing Container Builds.

Any documentation / pointers will be greatly appreciated. I want to use Google Container builder but this is currently the biggest obstacle.

Comment: When you say "We do have network connectivity to the BitBucket Server from the GCP Project where we'll be doing Container Builds", are you saying that your BitBucket Server has a publicly addressable (presumably authenticated) endpoint? Or are you saying that you run a VPC that can route to your BitBucket Server and that a VM in your GCP Project can thus access it?

Comment: Both. The public IP can be accessed from a list of white-listed IP addresses (e.g. VPN, company NAT address, etc.). BitBucket Server also runs in GCP but in a different project, with VPC routes so there is connectivity using internal IP addresses as well.

Comment: In terms of public APIs, you would need to roll your own solution for this by packaging the code from your on-prem BitBucket and shipping it to GCB via a GCS bucket. If you contact us at gcr-contact@google.com and provide full details, we may be able to offer additional solutions.